# How do I perform an IMAP search in Python (using Gmail and imaplib)?

Tags: python, gmail, imap

In Gmail, I have a bunch of labeled messages.

I'd like to use an IMAP client to get those messages, but I'm not sure what the search incantation is.

```
c = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
c.list()
('OK', [..., '(\\HasNoChildren) "/" "GM"', ...])
c.search(???)
```

I'm not finding many examples for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`imaplib` is intentionally a thin wrapper around the IMAP protocol, I assume to allow for a greater degree of user flexibility and a greater ability to adapt to changes in the IMAP specification. As a result, it doesn't really offer any structure for your search queries and requires you to be familiar with the [IMAP specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3501.html).

As you'll see in section "6.4.4.  SEARCH Command", there are many things you can specify for search criterion. Note that you have to `SELECT` a mailbox (IMAP's name for a folder) before you can search for anything. (Searching multiple folders simultaneously requires multiple IMAP connections, as I understand it.) `IMAP4.list` will help you figure out what the mailbox identifiers are.

Also useful in formulating the strings you pass to `imaplib` is "9.      Formal Syntax" from the RFC linked to above.

The `r'(\HasNoChildren) "/"'` is a mailbox flag on the root mailbox, `/`. See "7.2.6.  FLAGS Response".

Good luck!

Answer (score 9):

```
import imaplib 
obj = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
obj.login('username', 'password')
obj.select('**label name**') # <-- the label in which u want to search message
obj.search(None, 'FROM', '"LDJ"')
```

Answer (score 6):

[Labels are accessed exactly like IMAP folders](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?ctx=gmail&hl=en&answer=75725), according to Google.

Comment: This is not true.  You can't do conn.select("some-label-name").

Comment: @pyrony: Yes, you can.  Gmail **labels** are exposed as top-level IMAP **mailboxes**.  I'm not sure why they decided to do that rather than expose them as IMAP keywords, but that's what Gmail decided to do.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to use imaplib with Gmail is to use the `X-GM-RAW` attribute as described in the [Gmail Imap Extensions page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap_extensions#special-use_extension_of_the_list_command).

The process would be like this:

First connect to the account with the appropriate email and password:

```
c = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)
email = 'eggs@spam'
password = 'spamspamspam'
c.login(email, password)
```

Then connect to one of the folders/labels:

```
c.select("INBOX")
```

If necessary, you can list all the available folders/labels with `c.list()`.

Finally, use the search method:

```
gmail_search = "has:attachment eggs OR spam"
status, data = c.search(None, 'X-GM-RAW', gmail_search)
```

In the `gmail_search` you can use the same search syntax used in  [gmail advanced search](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en).

The search command will return the status of the command and the ids of all the messages that match your gmail_search.

After this you can fetch each messages by id with:

```
for id in data[0].split():
    status, data = gmail.fetch(id, '(BODY[TEXT])')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been pretty surprised that imaplib doesn't do a lot of the response parsing.  And it seems that responses were crafted to be hard to parse.

FWIW, to answer my own question:
    c.search(None, 'GM')

(I have no idea what the '(\HasNoChildren) "/"' part is about.)

Comment: This should be incorporated into the original question via an edit. (It is not an answer.)

Comment: @cdleary: Have you noticed `c.search(None, 'GM')` part. It might be the wrong answer. But It is an answer.

Comment: Oh, missed that. Sorry about that.

Comment: You mean `c.select(None, 'GM')`.